# If chat were easier to find, will resposted questions reduce?

Tags: discussion

A lot of first time users don't find an exact match to their questions but land at a lot of questions and answers that are almost what they want.

As a new user they cannot comment and post their exact question, which is then flagged and later marked as a duplicate.

Will making it easier for users to find chat reduce this? They could link the similar question in chat and get an exact answer. The earlier Q&A can then be updated to include quirks and workaround resulting from newer software version.

Answer (score 6):

If the search function on the landing page is too complicated, chat will not help.

Answer (score 6):

Chat actually *used* to be easier to find. It's link was right up there next to your inbox on the old SE top bar. It didn't help at all.

What people need to use more is the search feature.